# Popup rendering a black box instead of expected outcome

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following code to pop up a form:

```xml
<Window x:Class="PoolBet.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PoolBet"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="TogglePopupButton" Height="30" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Run Text="Is button toggled? " />
                    <Run Text="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=TogglePopupButton}" />
                </TextBlock>

                <Popup Name="myPopup" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=TogglePopupButton}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <!-- Added after TheGeneral's comment -->
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label Margin="0,10,0,0">Name:</Label>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,10,0,10" x:Name="nameInput" />
                        <Label Grid.Row="1">Amount:</Label>
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,10" x:Name="amountInput" />
                        <Label Grid.Row="2">Notes:</Label>
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" AcceptsReturn="True" x:Name="notesInput" />
                        <Button Click="submit" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Content="Submit"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Popup>
            </StackPanel>
        </ToggleButton>

        <ItemsControl Name="icTodoList" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,5">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <RadioButton Content="{Binding Choice}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <ListView Margin="10" Name="lvUsers" Grid.Column="2" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Amount" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Amount}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Notes" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Notes}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

(This is my Code-Behind, not sure if it matters though)

```cs
namespace PoolBet
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<User>();
        public ObservableCollection<Choice> Choices { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Choice>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lvUsers.ItemsSource = Users;
        }

        private void submit(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Users.Add(new User() { Name = nameInput.Text, Amount = Convert.ToInt32(amountInput.Text), Notes = notesInput.Text });
        }

        public class User
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public int Amount { get; set; }

            public string Notes { get; set; }
        }

        public class Choice
        {
            public string ChoiceName { get; set; }

            public ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

I want it to show a form with 3 fields (Name, Amount, Notes) but all I get is a black box and a fragment of the text fields, and the submit button.

[image: Black box with half of the text field and the submit button.]

I only started C# in earnest 2 days ago and I have no idea what went wrong. Can someone explain it please?

The popup with the grid color set to aqua:

[image: Set Grid colour to Aqua and Added a new rowdefinition]

The notes textfield was blocked: Added a new `<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />` and that seemed to fix it, although it is still cut in half.

Comment: Hrm, looks a little strange. Try explicitly setting the background color of the popup, grid or controls maybe, see what happens

Comment: @TheGeneral Yes the black changed to the specified color but it is still cut in half, with the submit button blocking the `notes` field. I will edit the post to show a screenshot.

Comment: I suspect the black background issue is due to Inheriting no background and having transparency issues. I also suspect you are having sizing issues due to not having any fixed width or height in your grid so it defaults to using the minimum amount of space possible - which ought to be fine but popups are finicky - maybe play around with padding or give the grid a margin or minwidth minheight. On a different note: probably give the popup the toggle button as a placement target and specify it should start below it so it moves with the window correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Transparency of the `Popup` (the `Popup` child host to be precise) is disabled by default, therefore the content of the `Popup` is renderd with a black background.

You must explicitely allow transparency on the `Popup` by setting `Popup.AllowsTransparency` property to true:

```
<Popup AllowsTransparency="True" />
```